# How to click selectbox or checkbox in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, jquery-selectbox

I want to make selectbox in CKeditor but:
- When i click selectbox in ckeditor it just show dialog to config select box.
==> I want to click that selectbox it have to show dropdown values to select. And after selected and submit form that view will be do not show selectbox, just show value you selected.

`When you select must be show dropdown values`

[image]

`After submit`

[image]

Comment: LOL. no one help me?

Answer (score 1):

In WYSIWYG ("edit") mode (when you are creating content in the editor) the form elements are editable, and not usable - because this is where you create your content. After your content is saved (or in preview mode) the created forms can actually be used (selected etc.).

In short CKEditor is a tool that you can use to create your forms for end users to fill in after your editor-created content lands on your page.